# Proofs involving sets and cross product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

So today I tried to solve two problems from a textbook involving sets again. I got stuck with the second one though I'm confident about my solution for the first problem. That's the task:

Prove for any subsets $A,B,C,D$ of a finite set $M$:
$$
a.)\; (A\times B)\cap(C\times D)=(A\cap C)\times(B\cap D)
$$

$$
b.)\; (A\times B)\cup(C\times D)\subset(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
(x,y)\in[(A\times B)\cap(C\times D)]&\Longleftrightarrow (x,y)\in(A\times B)\cap(x,y)\in(C\times D)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow(x\in A \land y\in B)\land(x\in C \land y \in D)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow(x\in A \land x\in C)\land(y\in B \land y\in D)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow[x\in(A\cap B)]\land[y\in(B\cap D)]\\
&\Longleftrightarrow(x,y)\in[(A\cap B)\times(B\cap D)].
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
(x,y)\in[(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)]&\Longleftrightarrow(x,y)\in(A\times B)\lor(x,y)\in(C\times D)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow(x\in A\land y\in B)\lor(x\in C\land y\in D)\\
\end{align}
$$

After that I tried a bunch of things but none of them seem to work out. I suspect that

$$
\begin{align}
(x\in A\land y\in B)\lor(x\in C\land y\in D)&\overset{(!)}{\implies}(x\in A \lor x\in C)\land(y\in B\lor y\in D)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow[x\in(A\cup C)]\land[y\in(B\cap D)]\\
&\Longleftrightarrow(x,y)\in[(A\cup C)\times(B\cap D)].
\end{align}
$$

but I couldn't explain why $(!)$ would imply my next step. One can easily see why equality wouldn't hold for $A=\{a\},\;B=\{b\},\;C=\{c\},\;D=\{d\}$ so my best bet for now is this implication.

Comment: Each item in your proof for part (a) should be a statement which is either true or false.  You are missing the red part here of $\color{red}{(x,y)\in}\left((A\cap B)\times (B\cap D)\right)$ in the final statement.  Similarly for the final line of your proof for part (b).

Comment: You're right; I'll fix this inattention immediately.

Comment: You can just write down a truth table, but I don't see the necessity here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implication (!) is true, maybe talking it out would help convince yourself. One of two possibilities must hold, the first requires that $x\in A$, and the second that $x\in C$. Similarly, one possibility requires $y\in B$ and another that $y\in D$.

Comment: I guess I was just wondering why the other way around wouldn't work. It's probably $\land$'s fault because everything would be cool if there were a "\lor" guy instead right?

Comment: Pretty much, the problem is that it would allow for either what you said or for the possibility of matching $x\in A$ with $y\in D$, etc.